# Selenium XPATH selecting next sibling

Tags: selenium, xpath, nextsibling

```
<div class="block wbc">
   <span></span>
   <span> text_value </span>
</div>
```

for getting text in second span where does below code go wrong?

```
driver.find_element(X_PATH,"*//div[@class='block']/span[1]")
```

For trying by yourself, maybe I write sth wrong here is link

[https://soundcloud.com/daydoseofhouse/snt-whats-wrong/s-jmbaiBDyQ0d?si=233b2f843a2c4a7c8afd6b9161369717&utm_source=clipboard&utm_medium=text&utm_campaign=social_sharing](https://soundcloud.com/daydoseofhouse/snt-whats-wrong/s-jmbaiBDyQ0d?si=233b2f843a2c4a7c8afd6b9161369717&utm%5C_source=clipboard&utm%5C_medium=text&utm%5C_campaign=social%5C_sharing)

And my code; still giving an error

```
playbackTimeline__duration =driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"*//div[@class='playbackTimeline__duration']/span[2]")
```

For finding web element clearly:

```
//*[@id="app"]/div[4]/section/div/div[3]/div[3]/div/div[3]/span[2]
```

But I will not use this way, I need declare with class method or CSS Selector at least

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sure that you always need the second span use this XPath:

```
*//div[@class='playbackTimeline__duration']/span[2]
```

If you need the first span that has actual text use this:

```
*//div[@class='playbackTimeline__duration']/span[normalize-space()][1]
```

If the @class has more than only playbackTimeline__duration in it you can use:

```
*//div[contains(@class,'playbackTimeline__duration')]/span[2]
```

If there are more div's like that use:

```
*//div[contains(@class,'playbackTimeline__duration')][1]/span[2]
```

Comment: I edited code, please look. None of them worked. I shared everything. Maybe my question was wrong

Comment: please edit your question so that the correct class is in your first example

Comment: what you mean by correct class is in your first example

Comment: `*//div[contains(@class,'playbackTimeline__duration')]/span[2]` worked

Comment: There is only one class "playbackTimeline__duration" in HTML

Comment: You use block in your example

Comment: I am confused. sorry. What do I have edit in question. The given div class block span element configuration doesnot resemble the actual(real) one from website?

Comment: That is correct, but since you have added the actual url , my examples are bases on that. Ik think for other visitors it will be clearer if you would change the question just based on the actual html